# Is it possible to receive Web Pushes in an electron app?

Tags: electron, onesignal, web-push

Is it possible to receive Web Pushes in an electron app?
I don't need to display the Notification, only data is important.

Maybe someone used Onesignal, successfully with electron?

Thanks!

Comment: This is now possible with [Pushy](https://pushy.me/docs/additional-platforms/electron) (Full disclosure: I founded Pushy)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately this isn't possible at the moment.

Web Push requires the browser vendor to maintain a server that keeps a connection open to each user to deliver notifications, and to store notifications while a device is offline. Electron has no such system set up for it.

It may be possible to extend Electron to use the operating system's built-in notification system. For example, Apple does have OS X notifications (currently supported by OneSignal), and Windows has a notification system built into it too (which OneSignal will support soon). Using this would require writing native extensions that bridge Electron to the operating system. This would have the added benefit of supporting notification delivery while your Electron app was not open.

Edit: This is now possible with [Pushy](https://pushy.me), a paid notification product that 
now supports Electron.

Comment: Does OneSignal plan to support Electron and maybe provide this  extension?

Comment: @JanekOlszak Not at this time. Our opinion is that integrating with the operating system's built-in remote notification system is a better approach. We've considered writing our own Electron to native-code bridge, but so far we haven't had the time to investigate this deeply.

Comment: Has there been any updates with this? I'm hoping to use one signal in my electron app

Comment: Have any body set the notifications from one-signal to  electron js ? Or they still not updated ?

Answer (score 2):

This is technically possible but requires a bit of lifting.  If you use the OneSignal REST API in your client you can add your device, and with electron-push-receiver (https://github.com/MatthieuLemoine/electron-push-receiver) you can receive and display the push notifications that OneSignal sends.

Start under "Add a device" in the REST docs here: https://documentation.onesignal.com/reference

You'll first register your device with FCM (firebase cloud messaging) and then pass that FCM token along to OneSignal via their REST API.

I just responded to this thread with a brief description of how to do this: https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Website-SDK/issues/98